# How to change selected text in ListView CheckBox

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-checkbox

I want to change selected text color when item is checked. I've made custom adapter to custom item with `TextView` and `CheckBox`

**Here is my item.xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/txtRow"
android:text ="TEST"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

<CheckBox
 android:id="@+id/ckbBox"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

**And my adapter:**

```
  public class ListViewAdapter : BaseAdapter,IOnCheckedChangeListener
{
    List<string> lstData = new List<string>();
    Activity activity;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    View itemView;
    public ListViewAdapter(Activity activity,List<string> lstData)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.lstData = lstData;
    }
    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return lstData.Count;
        }
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.ApplicationContext.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
        itemView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.item, null);

        TextView txtRow = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtRow);
        CheckBox ckbRow = itemView.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.ckbBox);

        ckbRow.SetOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        if (ckbRow.Checked)
            txtRow.Text = "HEHEHE";


        return itemView;

    }

    public void OnCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, bool isChecked)
    {
        if (isChecked)
        {
            var txtRow = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtRow);
            txtRow.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.White);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I checked on `CheckBox`, TextView don't change color as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need also edit your `GetView` method, probably it is refreshed, and color of text is still same. Try edit like this

```
 public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.ApplicationContext.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
        itemView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.item, null);

        TextView txtRow = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtRow);
        CheckBox ckbRow = itemView.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.ckbBox);

        ckbRow.SetOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        if (ckbRow.Checked)
          {
            txtRow.Text = "HEHEHE";

            txtRow.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.White);
          }
          else
          {
            //default color
            txtRow.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black); 
          }

        return itemView;

    }
```

Comment: Thank you but i want to change realtime when i clicked

Comment: When You clicked, it also  refresh view and color still same, becouse your method getView not valid it. Try set breakpoint in getView method and you see what happend after clik checkbox.